# Multiple hard drives prevents system boot

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios

I have four IDE hard drives connected to a motherboard through two IDE ribbons. On each ribbon, a drive is jumped as master and the other as the slave. When I have all four drives hooked up, the system will not boot. The BIOS freezes right after it auto-detects all four of the hard drives. Strangely, if I unplug the secondary master and slave the system will boot. It seems like anytime even one of the drives from the second ribbon cable is hooked up, the boot process freezes. Do I have a dead hard drive or is it something with having four hard drives together? How can I narrow down what my problem is? Thanks.

**problem components:**
MSI RD480 Neo2 motherboard
Seagate ST340015A (40GB primary master)
Maxtor 4D080H4 (80GB primary slave)
Seagate ST380013A (80GB secondary master)
Western Digital WD2500JB-00REA0 (250GB secondary slave)

Edit:
Problem Solved.
It turns out that two of the hard drives I was using, had died. I tried each one seperately and two were unresponsive. Thank you for the troubleshooting help.

Comment: You need to do way more troubleshooting.  Grab a notebook. Label the cables A and B.  You could label the hard drives. Note down which hard drives are on which cables.  Take the 2 hard drives that were on the primary, and the 2 hard drives that were on the secondary, and swap them over. Test.  Swap them back. so you're back in the original failed state. Now swap the cables over, so unplug the primary and secondary and swap them. Basic troubleshooting. You could then edit your post and describe the results.

Comment: You may find you can cause a crash in other ways than having all 4. And you may find some combinations  of 4 that don't crash. You will then have a better idea where the problem may be.

Comment: Have you tried on the "secondary cable", after you got a crash, switching around which hard drive was master and which was slave? If you have another hard drive, then you may be able to swap it for each hard drive on the secondary, and find one hard drive in particular that is picky.. and how it is picky. Once you find that, you can then put a label on it as to how it is picky. It also helps to have different IDE cables to try.

Comment: Another factor, is, and my memory may not be right on this, but sometimes a hard drive has one jumper option for "master", and another option for "master with a slave".. and of course no jumper in has a meaning too, a meaning specific to the drive.

Comment: Try using the CS jumper setting on all the drives. Use new IDE cables.

Comment: @Moab  or not using the CS jumper setting!  it never really caught on much and shouldn't ever be a necessity. but I suppose no harm in trying.  On a related note, there's no problem including 40 wire cables in troubleshooting here.. but know that there are issues with 40wire and cable select, and if using cable select that'd affect even the troubleshooting.  I think cable select could potentially just add a whole new dimension of issues in more things to try and not necessary, but may be worth a try.

Comment: You should be using 80 wire cables. Bad cables are the #1 cause of IDE problems.

Comment: @komidore64 Thanks for letting us know. But the system considers this question open -- could you add an answer of your own, and click the checkmark next to it to "accept" it? This will mark this question answered. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Beck Well, since he didn't even try with one hard drive before writing the question, the question is really rather useless, and the answer is no use to anybody else, but at least does tell us it's answered. The problem, is not that 4 hard drives crash it. 'cos even one crashes it. An editted answer seems more appropriate to me.. In time, the question will be long forgotton.

Comment: @barlop Except the system bumps it to the front page every now and then ;)

Comment: @Daniel Beck oh,  then maybe 0 ans is worse...Does it feed them to Google when there's no accepted ans, or when 0 ans? probably does! But no doubt we all agree that it's great that he came back and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bad hard drive. they were all quite old. I isolated one that was having read/write errors and removed it.

My apologies for leaving the question unanswered.